# Pulling value from table on website using VBA without any Names/IDs

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, html-table

I am using VBA to try to retrieve data from the county assessor's site. I have used getElementByName/ID etc. in other parts, but it seems that there are no identifiers and the data is just in a normal grid. Is there a way to retrieve this data with a different method? There are several other grids on this webpage, so I feel like it's hard to find.

Here's the HTML source code:

```
<div class="grid">
<table class="colborder w95">
<caption>Current Values</caption>
<thead><tr class="allborder"><th class="toleft">Type</th><th class="toleft">Class</th><th class="toright">Kind</th><th class="number">Land</th><th class="number">Bldg</th>
<th class="number">Total</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class=" ">
<td class="tobottom toleft " >2020&#160;Value</td>
<td class="tobottom toleft rowborder" >Residential</td>
<td class="toright rowborder">Full</td>
<td class="number rowborder">$73,600</td>
<td class="number rowborder">$225,300</td>
<td class="number rowborder">$298,900</td></tr>
```

The number I'm trying to pull is the bottom right of the table, which is $298,900 in this instance. The only thing I can think of to distinguish this section would be "Current Values", which is a caption for the grid. How would I use this caption to locate the table and pull the value from the bottom right corner?

Any help would be appreciated!

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the alternative approach to fetch the specific cell data from the HTML table.

You can try to access the element by `TagName` if the element does not contain ID, name, or any other attributes.

then after you can refer to the specific element using its index key value. Note that the index key starts from 0.

Sample code:

```
Sub demo()
 Dim IE
 Dim ro As Integer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://Your_site_address_will_be_here"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
          
    Set Table = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
               
     ro = 1
     For Each r In tRows
          Set tcells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each c In tcells
                If ro = 6 Then
                Debug.Print (c.innerText)
                ro = 0
                End If
                ro = ro + 1
            Next
     Next
         
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code example as per your own requirements.

Comment: Sorry for the OT Deepak-MSFT, but can you tell me with which program you create the animated GIFs for your explanations?

Comment: You can easily find the desired application by searching the **screen recorder gif maker** in the search engine. Let us know, whether the above code works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you. I always searched Google for screen recorders and got tools to record mp4. Then I ask you for animated GIFs and you tell me to ask Google for animated GIFs. Sometimes my brain is a mystery to myself.

Comment: The code works for me. However, I have completed the variable declarations and had to initialise IE via the GUID `Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")` But this has the reason of the local call of the HTML file. In the provided HTML I also closed the open tags. Since Joel Unick also wants to fetch data from other tables, I am not sure if this explanation is enough for him. But for a more detailed answer the HTML snippet is too small.

Comment: @Zwenn, Sorry. I thought you are the op and I confirm the solution with you.

Comment: Everything is good :-) A "little peer review" can't be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help Deepak! It ended up working after I iterated through the tables until I found the right one. This is exactly what I needed!!

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like your issue is solved now. I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is kind of clunky but worked for me:

```vb
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument, tbls As Object, tbl As Object

doc.body.innerHTML = Range("A2").Value 'your sample HTML with closing </table></div>...

Set tbls = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
For Each tbl In tbls
    If tbl.Caption.innerHTML = "Current Values" Then
        Debug.Print tbl.Rows(1).Cells(5).innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next tbl
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up running into a run-time error but I guarantee that's something on my end. I'm pretty novice when it comes to this stuff. I got it to work with Deepak's method.